# Need to pull in exact values with header in powershell data

Tags: powershell

I have code as below ,

```
      $uri = "https://www.postgresql.org/support/security/"
      $data = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
      $table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -first 2
      $table | select -ExpandProperty innertext
      Get-Service | Format-Table -Property Reference,Affected,Fixed
```

Here the values are not segregated to exact column header as needed.But i am getting like below with unformatted way.I am new to powershell.

**ReferenceAffectedFixedComponent & CVSS v3 Base ScoreDescription
CVE-2022-1552
Announcement
14, 13, 12, 11, 1014.3, 13.7, 12.11, 11.16, 10.21core server
8.8
AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H Autovacuum, REINDEX, and others omit "security restricted operation" sandbox**

Expected o/p:

Reference        Affected            Fixed                            Base_score   Description
CVE-2022-1552  14, 13, 12, 11, 10   14.3, 13.7, 12.11, 11.16, 10.21     8.8         Autovacuum,
REINDEX, and
others omit
"security
restricted
operation"

Please help me to achieve this in powershell .

Answer (score 0):

Rather than scraping the HTML contents as text, write a small utility function to build real objects from each row in the table:

```
function ConvertFrom-HtmlTable {
  param($table)

  # Discover header cells
  $headers = $table.tHead.getElementsByTagName('th') |% innerText

  # Iterate through all rows
  foreach($row in $table.getElementsByTagName('tr')){
    $data = [ordered]@{}
    $cells = $row.getElementsByTagName('td')

    for($ci = 0; $ci -lt $headers.Count; $ci++){
      # Populate object properties named after the header cells
      $data[$headers[$ci]] = $cells[$ci].innerText
    }

    # output object
    [pscustomobject]$data
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
foreach($table in $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -first 2){
    ConvertFrom-HtmlTable $_ |Format-Table Reference, Affected, Fixed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am getting error while running the last part combined with top one .Finally i have to export this data in CSV format to a particular directory .                                  Error :  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:19
+   foreach($row in $table.getElementsByTagName('tr')){
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull